# How to reduce subjectivity in the Baseline Inequality Index for meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, clinical-trials, confounding, meta-regression

I have recently come across an interesting means to appraise baseline differences in competing groups in clinical trials being pooled for meta-analysis: the **Baseline Inequality Index**.

As far as I am aware, there are no other similarly applicable approaches to explore the impact of baseline differences in a meta-analysis. It is reported in some detail in [*Ahmad et al, JAMA Intern Med 2015*](http://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/fullarticle/2210888), as follows:

> **Baseline Inequality Index**
>
> To assess the baseline inequality between
>   treatment and control groups in observational studies, and its
>   relationship with apparent benefit, we devised a simple baseline
>   inequality index. It needed to be a method that could be applied
>   across all studies even when data presentation was parsimonious,
>   lacking standard deviation information. To do this, we prepared a list
>   of baseline characteristics that are recognized markers of risk, as
>   follows: age, priormyocardial infarction, history of diabetes
>   mellitus, heart failure, peripheral arterial disease, hypertension,
>   presence of pulmonary edema, systolic blood pressure, and treatment
>   with angioplasty (in which the lack of treatment would confer
>   increased risk). Within each study, and for each marker, we assessed
>   whether the published central estimate (mean or median, whichever was
>   reported) was higher in the IABP group than the control group (which we
>   scored as +1) or lower (which we scored −1). If the values of a marker
>   were equal or not given, we scored 0. For each study, we totaled this
>   score. For the observational studies, we devised a simple index of
>   baseline inequality in risk factors between treatment and control
>   groups.

They then clarify how such Baseline Inequality Index can be exploited graphically and analytically, as follows:

> We then performed a random-effects metaregression using the baseline
>   inequality index as a moderator using the statistical programming
>   environment R and its “metafor” package. We generated a scatter
>   plot showing the relationship between the log OR of death and the
>   baseline inequality index, overlaid with the metaregression.

The main concern I have with this approach is the extent of subjectivity, which is quite large and potentially undermining a careful and accurate use of this index. Irrespective of the variable of interest, how can the score labelling become less subjective?

**How can we reduce such subjectivity of the Baseline Inequality Index?**

Comment: Do you mean subjective in the choice of markers or in extracting them from the primary article?

Comment: @mdewey Mainly in the scoring of the difference.